# Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I'm starting of with React-native and have already installed and launched the emulator. It works fine but when I try and run

```
react-native run-android
```

I get these in the console

```
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:12384) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 970 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\##\ShoppingList\android\local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

I tried deleting "wide data" and also `./gradlew clean` but neither work

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that this I'm running it on a windows machine. My issue was not having this:
[JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

It works well now

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

1. Go to your React-native Project -> Android
2. Create a file local.properties
3. Open the file
4. paste your Android SDK path like below
5. sdk.dir = C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
   Replace USERNAME with your user name

Now, Run the react-native run-android in your terminal.

**Method 2:**

1. Open the Windows Control Panel.
2. Click on User Accounts, then click User Accounts again
3. Click on Change my environment variables Click
4. on New... to create a new ANDROID_HOME user variable that points to
   the path to your Android SDK:
   [image]